# How to fix TPS in jemeter irrespective of threads

Tags: java, spring-boot, performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am running tests in Jmeter, where a thread group is having 5 APIs. Now, the sum of hits for all the APIs is required to be fixed irrespective of the number of threads. For example, no matter what is the number of threads, I need to keep the TPS as 200. How can that be achieved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are in:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) however it's precise enough on "minute" level so during first minute of your test you may get higher TPS
2. [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) which is very "precise" but you need to specify throughput period duration, test duration, think about [pool of free threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)
3. [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin) which provides easy visual way of configuring the TPS and it can also be integrated with [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) so JMeter would be able to kick off extra threads if current amount is not sufficient for conducting the required load.

Comment: Can you please explain if the number of threads has any relation with the TPS here because if the TPS is going to remain constant, how does it depend on the number of threads.

Comment: TPS is a number of "Transactions per second" and it mainly depends on the number of users and your application response time. If you have 1 user and 1 second response time the TPS will be 1. 2 users and 1 second response time - TPS will be 2, 2 users and 2 seconds response time - TPS will be 1, 2 users and 0.5 seconds response time - TPS will be 4, etc. see [How do I Correlate the Number of (Concurrent) Users with Hits Per Second](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420695-How-do-I-Correlate-the-Number-of-Concurrent-Users-with-Hits-Per-Second) for more information.

Comment: That's absolutely correct. But here the Constant Throughout Timer seems to disregard the number of threads or any other condition, and keep the thoroughput constant, can you please explain how that's happening?

Comment: By default any JMeter thread (virtual user) will execute Samplers as fast ast it can. When Constant Throughput Timer is being executed it checks the current throughput and if it's too high it introduces a delay to slow down JMeter virtual user in order to reach and maintain the target throughput. It doesn't work into another direction, i.e. it cannot make JMeter requests execution faster. See [How to Use JMeter's Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) article for more details.